# Using a set of points with x, y coordinates as a function f and calculating f(x) for x in [Set.xmin, Set.xmax] (in C++)

Tags: c++, set, linear-algebra

Quick rundown, doing first year CS at uni in France, doing an exercise on structs. But that's no where near what I've got for you today.
I've got a solution that works, so no need to worry about that. **I just want to know if this is a good way of getting the job done.** And how I could improve it.

Note: I'm only allowed to use the libraries/functions seen in class, so: iostream, array and a few others.

So here what I've got to do: I get a set of points with *x, y* coordinates. Say A(3, -1) B(1, 2) C(0, 2) and D(-3, 1)
From the line that these points draw I have my function *f(x)*, and I have to calculate *y* from any *x in [-3,3]*.

Note: A -> f(3)=-1 , B -> f(1) = 2, etc...

First I've got a function that makes sure that all the points are ordered as to have a continuous function (this was also the previous question in the exercise sheet). I also get the function order 'direction' from there. If (*for all x[i] of the array, x[i+1]>x[i]*) the direction is positive.
With the example set above the function returns -1 showing that the set is 'backwards'. *For all x[i] of the array {3,1,0,-3} x[i+1] < x[i]* so the direction is -1.

Note: I could write a sort algorithm, but I'm supposed to only request valid sets of points, so no need.

Using the direction I search up the x values to get a closest left and right point (or equal value in which case I just return the y of the point).
With A,B,C,D I'd start looking at D, since the direction is -1. This is so I can check for values to the left of x first then check for a value above.
Then it's pretty straight forward from there to calculate f(x) using f(xl) and f(xr).

The direction was a tricky part for me, backward sets, and sets that crossed from negative to positive gave me some NaNs, but in the end the process I've described and will post below seems to work.

I've also added a check to make sure the x provided is within range, but that's probably be beyond the exercise.

```
struct point {
    float x,y;
};

using points = array<point, buffSize>;
struct enspoint {
    points p;
    int nb;
};

int absord (enspoint a) {
    for(int i=1;i<a.nb;i++){
        if(a.p[i].x<a.p[i-1].x){
            for(int j=a.nb-1;j>0;j--){
                if(a.p[j].x>a.p[j-1].x){
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

float image (enspoint a, float x){
    float xl, xr, xratio, ylrdelta, ydelta, y;
    int c = absord(a);
    if(!c) return 0;

    int i; bool gendarmes = 1;
    if(c==1) i = 0;
    else if (c==-1) i=a.nb-1;
    while(gendarmes) {
        if(x==a.p[i].x)return a.p[i].y;
        if(x>a.p[i].x) {
            xl=i;
        } else {
            xr=i;
            gendarmes = 0;
        }
        i+=c;
    }

    xratio = (x-a.p[xl].x)/(a.p[xr].x-a.p[xl].x);
    ylrdelta = a.p[xr].y-a.p[xl].y;
    ydelta = xratio*ylrdelta;
    y=a.p[xl].y + ydelta;
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Your question isn not clear. What is the direction? The STL has algorithms for doing the kind of things you describe in one line. For instance, have a  look at `sort`, `lower_bound`, in the `algorithm` header file.

Comment: I've made some notes, and added some detail.
Essentially direction: 
If for all x[i] of the array, x[i+1]>x[i] the direction is positive.

And I can't use function like sort, lower_bound, etc.. we have to use only our own algorithms. The actual name of the subject I'm doing the work for is algorithmique_2

Comment: Are you synthesising a function such that `f(3)` -> -1, `f(1)` -> 2, `f(0)` -> 2 and `f(-3)` -> 1, interpolating between those points?

Comment: it's exactly that Caleth

Comment: I would suggest writing a `sort`, a `lower_bound` and an `upper_bound`, that behave the same as the `std::` counterparts. Then write your solution in terms of those. In the process of that, you might discover you are writing other functions that match things in `std::`, that's fine, as a learning exercise. The important thing is they only get written *once*

Comment: If you want help with a specific problem, you need to narrow the question down to that particular problem. If you rather want a general review of working code, then post at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but then make sure to copy/paste the full code including a test case with main() and read what's on-topic on that site, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help.

Comment: I'll look at codereview, thanks. What should I do with this question then?

@Caleth I've been told to keep code DRY. I probably have an upper and lower bound function already written in a previous exercice. I should find out how to make and include my own libraries.
As for sorting algorithms, I think we should be doing those this semestre, but I'll probably try to get a head start and add one to this.

Comment: generally all you need is to write a file that only contains forward declarations. Traditionally these have a `.h` (or `.hpp`) file extension, but any filename works. If you search your compiler's path, there will be files named `vector` and `algorithm` etc.